# Calling non-default PLSQL object constructor function from Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, constructor

I know how to call default PL/SQL constructor from Java. I wanna know how to call non-default constructor.

PL/SQL Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT IS OBJECT(
    DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER,
    DEPARTMENT CHARACTER VARYING(100),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION OBJ_DEPARTMENT RETURN SELF AS RESULT, --1st constructor
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION OBJ_DEPARTMENT(department VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT --2nd constructor
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY OBJ_DEPARTMENT
IS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION OBJ_DEPARTMENT RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END;

    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION OBJ_DEPARTMENT(department VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    IS
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
            BEGIN
                :1:=SEQ_DEPARTMENTS.NEXTVAL();
            END;
        ' USING OUT DEPARTMENT_ID;
        SELF.DEPARTMENT:=department;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

Java Code:

```
//calling 1st constructor
StructDescriptor structDescriptor=StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("OBJ_DEPARTMENT", oracleConnection);
STRUCT objDepartment=new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, new Object[]{1, "Information Technology"});
```

I tried to pass a single String argument in the Object[] to match the parameter in the 2nd constructor...

```
STRUCT objDepartment=new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, new Object[]{"Accounting"});
```

...but didn't work.
How to call the constructor function inside a PL/SQL object?

Answer (score 0):

Inside PL/SQL you can call:

```
declare
  t  OBJ_DEPARTMENT;
begin
  t := OBJ_DEPARTMENT(); -- this call of your first constructor without params
end;
/
```

or

```
declare
  t  OBJ_DEPARTMENT;
begin
  t := new OBJ_DEPARTMENT('Some value'); -- this call of your second constructor with 1 string param
end;
/
```

`new` keyword is optional.

Btw, why do you use dynamic SQL to get nextval from the sequence? In Oracle 11 and higher you can do following:

```
    SELF.DEPARTMENT := SEQ_DEPARTMENTS.NEXTVAL;
```

In earlier versions you need to do:

```
    select SEQ_DEPARTMENTS.NEXTVAL into SELF.DEPARTMENT from dual;
```